# change sub string in xml file with python

Tags: python-3.x, replace, innerhtml, str-replace

i'm trying to change the symbols `&lt;` and `&gt;` in xml file :

```
    &lt;divclass="specific_info_group"&gt;
    &lt;divclass="specific_info_title"&gt;model&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;divclass="specific_info_txt"&gt;
```

i have tried to replace it with re:

```
        re.sub('&lt;','<',desc)
        re.sub('&gt;','>', desc)
```

the code doesn't change anything and i'm still getting those symbols.
also, i have tried to work with this :

```
        desc.replace('&lt;','<')
        desc.replace('&gt;', '<')
```

but still im not getting the html format in the output XML file

any solution ?

Comment: I think that you need to use CDATA, but then your question lacks an exemple.

Comment: hi - i will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

As it is escaped html you should use a html parser to unescape.

```py
desc = """
    &lt;divclass="specific_info_group"&gt;
    &lt;divclass="specific_info_title"&gt;model&lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;divclass="specific_info_txt"&gt;
    """

import html.parser
parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
bla = parser.unescape(desc)

print(bla)
#    <divclass="specific_info_group">
#    <divclass="specific_info_title">model</div>
#    <divclass="specific_info_txt">
```

Comment: hi @Frank - i have tried this , but i'm still getting these symbols . im trying to do it when i'm scrapping the data from the url . it looks that i'm getting the symbols when i'm writing to the xml file  .

Comment: How are you scraping? Can you provide a working sample?